# Fancybox and Chrome / Firefox

Tags: image, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, fancybox

i got a "little" bug on my website. Here is the code im using:

product.tpl

```
{else}
                                            href="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $imageIds, 'thickbox_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"
                                            data-fancybox-group="other-views"
                                            class="fancybox{if $image.id_image == $cover.id_image} shown{/if}"
```

global.css

```
.fancybox-skin {
  background: #f4f5f7 !important; }

.fancybox-skin .fancybox-close {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f4f5f7!important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px; }
  .fancybox-skin .fancybox-close:hover {
    color: #515151; }
  .fancybox-skin .fancybox-close:after {
    content: "\f057";
    font-family: "FontAwesome"; }
```

Here is a [Link](http://evoxity.net/en/uplay/2-watchdogs.html) to a product.

If you enlarge the picture by clicking on it, and hover to one of the sites and than jump to one of the other pictures you can see that the background is moving. In Internet Explorer it is working fine.

---

Now:

```
    /* 1920x1200 ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1681px) {
/* Styles */
body {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 1.42857;
background: #f4f5f7 url('http://evoxity.net/themes/default-bootstrap/img/background/1920x1200.jpg');
margin: 0 ;
background-repeat: no-repeat scroll;
-moz-background-size:cover;
overflow: auto;
background-position:center 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Because you have a fixed background in the `body` which shifts 17px to the right (cause that's what fancybox does)... you may want to remove the `fixed` rule, center the background and repeat it vertically like  `body {  background: url("http://evoxity.net/themes/default-bootstrap/img/background/1366x768.jpg") repeat-y scroll center 0 #f4f5f7;...}` that should do the trick.

Comment: Hey JFK check my edit in the first post :)

Comment: what about `background-position:center 0;`

Comment: Check update, current problems are these: current background isnt fixed, so it always repeat instead of just move the content in the container and it doesnt cover the browser window in terms of height anymore. As an example the 1920x1200 background got a E on the right bottom border, this one is cutted off. Seems a bit like i can decide between working backgrounds or a working fancybox.